# How to handle Core Data custom methods what return an object or nil in Obj C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a Core Data project with entities **Person** and **PersonEvent**.
There is a many-to-one relationship (personEvents) between PersonEvent and the Person.
An PersonEvent can have a type like **birth**, death... a date ...
In the CoreDataProperties file of the Person entity, I made a custom method called personBirthDate which should return an NSDate.

```
-(NSDate *)personBirthDate
{
    NSDate * birthDate;

    // Use the relationship to get the related events
    NSArray *personEventsArray = [self.personEvents allObjects];

    // loop array to find an event of type birth
    // get the NSDate of the event in the PersonEvent
    // return the  birthDate;
    // code here ....

    return birthDate;
}
```

The Person.personBirthDate is used with binding in some views.
The code doesn't crash, as an event that hasn't got a Date doesn't exist and will not be displayed, but quiet correctly so, xcode complains with "nil returned from a method..."
If there are NO events with type **birth** linked to the Person, this method would return nil.

What is the best or a better way to implement this?

Comment: what is declared on the interface? maybe in the interface you have `-(NSDate * __nonnull)personBirthDate;`

Comment: '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *personBirthDate;'
when I change it to
'@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate *personBirthDate;'
it's fine.
I never though about it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me make it an answer instead of a comment.

Check the interface of your class as it seems that the method return type is a `nonnull` type, meaning the return value should never be `nil`

One solution is changing `nonnull` to `nullable`, this indicates that the return can be a nil value.

here is an apple blog that talks about nonnull and nullable key: [link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

Snippet of the topic:

> `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull`. As you might expect, a`_Nullable` pointer may have a NULL or nil value, while a `_Nonnull` one should not. The compiler will tell you if you try to break the rules.